# I was attempting to run a minecraft server on 1.8.9 on my raspberry pi. I followed a tutorial and when I attempted to run it is gave this message

Tags: linux, hosting, minecraft-pi-edition

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this and how to fix it? I am not familiar with Linux and would like some help/[image: The image]

Answer (score 1):

Let me introduce you to a huge component of debugging. Taking your error and googleing it.

That brought me to our sister site about Ubuntu. https://askubuntu.com/questions/695560/assistive-technology-not-found-awterror

I don't understand much of it, but if I read this right, you got the wrong version of OpenJDK (Open Java DevKit?)

Comment: Indeed, openjdk is open java devkit. aka java development kit.